# Serializable class with ISerializable constructor

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, serializable

Is it possible to declare the class `[Serializable]`, and yet add a
constructor with the signature `(SerializationInfo information, StreamingContext context)` to do some specific task at the time of deserialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either inherit `ISerializable` or just add a couple custom methods to your class that are called during serialization/deserialization.

These methods are decorated with special attributes that tell the serializer to call them:

[OnDeserializedAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

[OnDeserializingAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializingattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

[OnSerializedAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.onserializedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

[OnSerializingAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.onserializingattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

MSDN has a great tutorial (which I don't need to duplicate here) on how to use these attributes:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and see the links provided for each attribute for implementing methods for each.